# Add +1 or -1 on value when clicking on a icon

Tags: php, jquery

I'm looking for a way to automatically add +1 to the number when a user clicks the icon or -1 if the user clicks again. My code adds already in the back a +1 or -1, so that event is already covered. But I want that only the number right from that particular icon is being added. The problem is that I have 32 icons on that same page, so the code should only do an action on the number in that span on not all span's and without refreshing the page every time a user clicks on an icon.

```
<span class="float-right">
  <a href="#" id="1234" class="favorite">
    <i class="fas fa-heart" style="color:#dc3545"></i></a>
   1
 </span>

<span class="float-right">
  <a href="#" id="12345" class="favorite">
     <i class="fas fa-heart" style="color:#dc3545"></i></a>
  1
</span>
```

This is the jQuery code for toggling the icon.

```
$('.favorite').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   vote(this);
   $("i", this).toggleClass("far fa-heart fas fa-heart");
});
```

This is the vote function

```
function vote(_obj) {    
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                data: "id=" + $(_obj).attr("id"), 
                url: "vote.php"
            });  
        }
```

Comment: is your `vote` function sending an ajax request? It might be useful to see that function

Comment: I added it! Thanks!

Comment: presumably the duplicate IDs is just in the question. As the `vote` function only sends the ID attribute the work of toggling between 1 and -1 needs to be done in the `vote.php` script or possibly even the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below example *(ignore my `html` because I used font awesome 4)*

```js
$('.favorite').each(function(e) {
  let clicked = false;
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let text = +$(this).children('.count').text();
    //vote(this); // exclude to avoid error
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o');
    if (!clicked) {
      $(this).children('.count').addClass('plus').text(parseInt(0 + 1))
      clicked = true;

    } else {
      $(this).children('.count').removeClass('plus').text(parseInt(0 - 1))
      clicked = false;

    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none
}

span.count.plus::before {
  content: "+";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="float-right">
  <a href="#" id="1234" class="favorite">
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-heart" style="color:#dc3545"></i>
   <span class="count">0</span>
</a>
</span>

<span class="float-right">
  <a href="#" id="12345" class="favorite">
     <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-heart" style="color:#dc3545"></i>
  <span class="count">0</span>
</a>
</span>

<div>
  <i class="fa fa-snowflake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-snowflake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-snowflake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pedram! But now you just add +1 as a text, how can I really add + 1 and - 1 to that value?

Comment: @GlennS you mean as an `int` ?

Comment: Yes, when that is fixed. After that I only need to see what the current class is to detect to -1 or +1.

Comment: Yes, but can it be that it still does the +1 as a text?

Comment: @GlennS I don't understand what you mean, please explain more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205376/discussion-between-glenn-s-and-pedram).